# Novice soldering - burnt board

Tags: pcb

[image]I am replacing a toaster oven heating element and found this loose connection & burn on the circuit board. Does this look like I could successfully solder it back in place?

Thanks.

[image: Burnt board]

Comment: You certainly can solder it back to a reasonable degree, but consider that this connector has de-sodered itself for some more serious reason.

Comment: what was plugged onto that tab?

Comment: The heating element I am replacing was connected.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to solder that back. Be 100% **sure** to use electronic grade flux core solder and not plumbing solder.

It looks to me like the assembler was rough and cracked the solder joint (latent failure), which then oxidized and heated up causing the damage you see. The heating is apparently confined to just the joint area, so I don't think anything else is wrong.

Maybe try cleaning the area with an old toothbrush and isopropanol and then gently scraping the solder mask off (leaving clean copper) around the connections. If the connection doesn't look perfect, lay a wire from the pads to that bare section of the trace it connects to and run solder all over it.

Comment: The heating that caused the solder to melt was because the terminal pushed onto that tab was loose - there are arc marks visible on the tab. Replace the terminal so that it's a tight fit onto the tab, or it'll happen again.